# Vertical Centering a span

Tags: html, css

So I have these three columns of content. I am using The [1140 Grid](http://cssgrid.net) in my layout.

This is how it normally (and should) look like:

[image: http://imgur.com/KQfPr89]

But when the heading goes multiline, it goes like this:

[image: http://imgur.com/N8s96jA]

Here's the HTML code for that bit:

```
<div id="sub-hero" class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="post fourcol">
            <a href="">
                <div class="thumb"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/380/160" alt="Placeholder"></div>
                <div class="meta">
                <span>
                    <h2>Making Sense Of This</h2>
                    <em class="byline">By Name Author</em>
                </span>
                </div>  
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="post fourcol">
            <a href="">
                <div class="thumb"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/380/160" alt="Placeholder"></div>
                <div class="meta">
                <span>
                    <h2>How To Not Train A Megatron-sized Dragon</h2>
                    <em class="byline">By Name Author</em>
                </span>
                </div>          
            </a>

        </div>
        <div class="post fourcol last">
            <a href="">
                <div class="thumb"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/380/160" alt="Placeholder"></div>
                <div class="meta">
                <span>
                    <h2>Sample Post With A Super Long Headline</h2>
                    <em class="byline">By Name Author</em>
                </span>
                </div>              
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the corresponding CSS code:

```
.container#sub-hero .post .meta span { 
    display: inline-block; 
    margin-top: 0.5em; 
    vertical-align: middle; 
}

.container#sub-hero .post .meta { 
    color: #fff; 
    padding: 0.7em 1em 1em 1em; 
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 0; 
    width: 100%; 
    z-index: 2; 
}
```

Any fix? Thanks!

Comment: Does it happen only when `.fourcol .last` div, or any div where a line break happens?  And by line break (since you seem to have put the working code), do you mean and HTML line break (ie `<br />`), or a normal line break (ie `\n`)?  Also, your image doesn't show the full header it appears.  Is it hidden underneath content below? is is lower in the div? Does it disappear altogether?

Comment: Although you've added code it's hard to get a test environment for this... Anyway, have you tried adding white-space:nowrap; to the heading? It should at least keep it all in one line, and be a good starting point.

Comment: @Jon it happens on all blocks. No line breaks.

Comment: @Omega Applying `no-wrap` to the meta merely overlaps everything. If it will be applied to just `h2`, the text will just widen, essentially 'no-wrap', but it's still misplaced at the bottom.

Comment: @RaffyAlcoriza (Just a note, it's nowrap). The nowrap was a starting point, so once it gets it onto one line, you could try font sizes, like 100% for example... But without a live preview it's quite difficult to trouble shoot something like this. If you are able to get a live preview then do let me know..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, figured it out, also thanks to the help of Omega.

Here's what I added to the codes:

```
.container#sub-hero .post .meta { 
    white-space:nowrap; /*expands the whole thing*/
    width: 100%; 
}

.container#sub-hero .post .meta span { width: inherit; } /*adjusts the byline, at least, to fit inside the box width and not overflow*/
.container#sub-hero .post .meta h2 { white-space:normal; } /*to reset the h2 to its normal fling*/
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You should set `display: table-cell; text-align: center;` to `.row` and `display: block;` to `.meta` and also to `span` element and don't forget to define `display: block;` to `<a>` element. If this doesn't work, please add your full css or add fiddle like **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/Y7PhV/101/)**.
Keep your css tag there and update and share.